# Why I am getting "HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>" while passing my django views data in javascript fucntion?

Tags: javascript, html, api, django-templates

I am all new to javascript. I was working on a Django project to make a social networking app. I am having a problem with the like-button that will update the colour of the like button and the number of likes asynchronously without reloading the page. Here I'm sharing my  Django template having the like button's code.

```html
<form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" id="likeform" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button id = "like" class="btn btn-link">Like</button>
    </form>
    
    <small id="num_of_likes">{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
```

Through the button containing `id = "like"`, my javascript code will receive the Django template variable and fetch API from Django. Here is my js code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    document.querySelector('#like').addEventListener('click', ()=> like_function('like'));
})


function like_function(like){
    fetch(`/index/${posts_id}`,{
        method:"POST",
        body : JSON.stringify({
            "is_like" : is_like,
            "num_like" : num_like,
        })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Unike";
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector('#like').innerHTML = "Like";
        }
    })
}
```

Although my Django views method returns JSON data, I want my js code will get that JSON data and returns back to my homepage. Here's what error I got:
[image]

I didn't get what was actually going on. I want my javascript method will take me back to my homepage. Here's I have seen what's I am actually facing off.
https://youtu.be/PV6ctAQNA64

Comment: It the call stack, `<anonymous>` refers to the anonymous arrow function you've attached to `HTMLButtonElement` as an event, then it shows the actual function where the error was fired (`at like_function`). The actual error is, that you're using an undeclared variable `posts_id` in `fetch(\`/index/${posts_id}\`,{`.

Comment: So, how can I get rid of this?

Comment: ?? Declare and assign a value to `posts_id` variable.